# How to optimumly perform a MySQL query on a datetime column using only the time component

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a mysql datetime column I want to query against, however I only want to query time of day component of the datetime column, however I believe using the functions HOUR() MINUTES() etc create full table scans. Thus using the query below is not optimum.

```
SELECT datetime_col
FROM articles
WHERE TIME(datetime_col) > "09:00:00" 
   && TIME(datetime_col) < "13:00:00"
```

What would the best way be to query the time component?

Comment: your best bet would be to have columns of datatype time and index them...

Comment: @fancyPants - that's what I was thinking but am hoping there is some mid level solution that doesn't mean updating my schema.